# How to paginate datatables so the datas won't load together in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Loading all the data at once will make the page load slower. Is there any way to load only 10 records and load the others if the user clicks to page 2 or something?

Below is the code I used to load all data. It works just fine but when I import 5,000 records, it crashes the page to error 500 because of the slow loading

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::all();
    $documents = Receiving::where('draft', '=', 0)->get();

    return view('documents/index', compact('users', 'documents'));
}
```

when I use `paginate();` it would only show 1 page

Comment: you can use ```paginate()``` and change query param```page``` to set page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use paginate with parameter, like this:

```
$documents = Receiving::where('draft', '=', 0)->paginate(20);
```

Use this in view:

```
 <div class="pagination">
      {{ $documents->render() }} or {{ $documents->links() }}
 </div>
```

Comment: I used this and it would only show 20 records. The other records and pages would be hidden

Comment: I edited my response again. I think it is work for you. @newbie

Comment: It works. Thank you. It has 2 pagination now (bootstrap and the links) but it is a different problem.

Comment: You can use `render` or `links`. which you want :) @newbie